# Postgresql: BIG (over 24h) Interval hh:mm:ss conversion to a date (excel, power query, power BI proper interval reading)

Tags: excel, postgresql, date, datetime, powerquery

I am downloading data from PostgreSQL to excel, in interval format hh:mm:ss such: '233:51:46'. I need to use this data in such shape in Power Query, PowerBi and finally in excel.

To be honest excel is the smartest tool from this three mentioned, because to read it as a interval it will automatically convert that interval from: '233:51:46' to a full date: '09.01.1900  17:51:46'.
I've noticed that excel convert to a date every interval hh:mm:ss which has value over '23:59:59', values 24:00:00 and bigger will be converted in a date shape 'yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss, so that excel understand it as a big interval (value over 23:59:59).

Unfortunately Power Query and PowerBI aren't so smart and do not want to make any kind of conversion as excel does and treat bigger intervals (values over 23:59:59) as an error. But when I give them bigger intervals converted by excel to a date shape they understand it as time and I can make conversions within PowerQuery/PowerBI.
And my question is, are there any PostgreSQL ways to convert '233:51:46' in the same way as excel does, so that I will have done this conversion on the PostgreSQL level and download proper, understandable date format, intervals with bigger values than 23:59:59 to PowerQuery/PowerBI.

enter image description here

Hopefully I didn't mess up anything in that problem description

Comment: Excel gives bigger inervals (over 23:59:59) NonStandard format = [h]:mm:ss. Smaller intervals (below 23:59:59) excel gives NonStandard format = hh:mm:ss.

Comment: An interval is a _duration_, it's **not** a "point in time" Converting something like "233 hours, 51 minutes and 46 seconds" to a point in time does not make sense. But if you really want to, you could add that to a date, e.g. `date '1900-01-01' + interval '233:51:46'` yields `1900-01-10 17:51:46`

Comment: Finally figured that out, yeah:). To deal with big intervals (over 24 hours value) and download them into PowerQuery or BI from Postgresql, so that PowerQuery or BI can read them as a decimal value, before everything U must in Postgresql script convert values in interval columns into a seconds number by using function, e.g.: SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM INTERVAL '5 days 3 hours'); Result: 442800. Then U have to divide them into 60 (U gain minutes values then) and again into 60 (U gain hours values then) and again by 24 (U gain days values then). Then, interval values are the same as from excel.